# Copiar dados de uma coluna de uma tabela para outra da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

ola pessoal eu estou com uma duvida. Preciso copiar os dados de uma coluna do inteiro para outra coluna do tipo decimal da mesma tabela, isso no MySQL. É possível fazer ? pode haver alguma inconsistências nos dados? E como posso fazer?

Comment: Na verdade não precisa nem copiar, nesses casos pode simplesmente editar a tabela mudando o tipo. MAS, eu acho sempre bom copiar e deletar a anterior quando é pra mudar tipo, pra evitar mão de obra consertando desastres  ;)

Comment: Valeu pessoal. Me ajudaram mto. Acho que vou tentar primeiro alterar o campo para decimal numa base teste para depois no ir para o banco real.

Comment: Você pode responder sua propria pergunta, caso tenha encontrado a solução diferente das respostas.

Comment: sim é possível, se fosse o contrário poderia ter problemas.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi bem o que você deseja fazer, mas me parece algo bem simples. Tente fazer o seguinte, veja se lhe ajuda:

```
update tabela
set coluna_decimal = coluna_inteira
```

Answer (score 2):

Só mudar o tipo, já irá resolver o problema:

```
 ALTER TABLE `nome_da_tabela` 
 CHANGE `nome_da_coluna_inteiro` `nome_da_coluna_decimal` DECIMAL (6,2);
```

E para copiar os dados, você pode fazer um insert com select:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

INSERT INTO tabela_destino
(campo1, campo2, campo3)
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabela_origem;
```